OutputChannel.show doesn't always show the channel in the Output view
In our custom extension, we use OutputChannel.show in various places but it does not always switch the Output view to the respective channel, even when passing false for preserveFocus. The channel is created, but not immediately shown. Are there particular conditions when the channel will be actually shown when using this method?

related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60689, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117957. if you raise a new issue ticket, make sure to include a repro, and please add a link here to your issue ticket.
